# complex sum of reciprocal decimal expansions terminating in odd digits

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let bn be the sequence of all positive integers such that the decimal expression for 
1/bn
terminates in an odd digit:
1, 2, 4, 8, 10, . . .
(For instance, 3 is not included because 1/
3 = 0.33 . . . does not terminate, 4 is included
because 1/
4 = 0.25 terminates in 5, which is odd; 5 is not included because 1/
5 = 0.2
terminates in 2, which is even.)
Find sum to infinity 1/bn

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm not able to prove it right now, but I'm quite sure this sum tends to infinity. I would try to prove that there is a k such that $\sum_n{\frac{1}{b_n}}>\sum_n{\frac{1}{k\times n}}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_n{\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: i used calculator to see if thier was a pattern among the integers which would produce the wierd property . there wasnt a pattern and if thier was it may have just been looked at as a geometric series . ( possibly  with other terms ) i cant see any pattern . that has to be the direction to go i would think.

Comment: If focus on numbers $a_n$ such that the decimal expression for $1/a_n$ is finite, then $$
a_n = 5^x 2^y; \qquad(x,y\in\mathbb{Z},\:x\ge 0,\: y\ge 0).
$$
And $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{5^x2^y} = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{5^x}\left(\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^y}\right) =\\ 
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{5^x}\left(\dfrac{2}{2-1}\right) = 2\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{5^x} = 2\cdot\dfrac{5}{5-1}=\dfrac{5}{2}.$$ Therefore (since $1/b_n$ terminate in an **odd digit**) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n < 5/2.$

Comment: @Oleg567 Ok, so it seems I was wrong (but only of an infinite order of magnitude, not that much). I didn't know of this property for finite decimal expression. I guess it make sense, since finite decimal expression of $1/a$ means $\exists n , a | 10^n$. For Randin, use Oleg comment, and try find a property on $x$ or $y$ from the odd digit condition

Comment: Correction to my prev. comment: there should be sums $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{a_n}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{b_n}$ written (accordingly).

Answer (score 2):

**A.** 
Each number $a_n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the decimal expression for $1/a_n$ is finite, $-$ has (why?) the form
$$
a_n = 5^x 2^y; \qquad(x,y\in\mathbb{Z},\:x\ge 0,\: y\ge 0).\tag{1}
$$

**B.**
If $x>y$, then $a_n = 10^y\cdot 5^{x-y}$, and the last decimal digit of $1/a_n$ is $2,4,6$ or $8$.

If $x=y$, then $a_n = 10^x$, and the last decimal digit of $1/a_n$ is  $1$.

If $x<y$, then $a_n = 10^x\cdot 2^{y-x}$, and the last decimal digit of $1/a_n$ is  $5$.

**C.** So each number $b_n\in\mathbb{N}$ (such that the decimal expression for $1/b_n$ terminates in an **odd digit**) has the form
$$
b_n = 5^x 2^y; \qquad(x,y\in\mathbb{Z},\:0\le x\le y).\tag{2}
$$

**D.** Therefore (due to convergence of all considered subseries)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{b_n} = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=x}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{5^x2^y} = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{5^x}\left(\sum_{y=x}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^y}\right) =\\ 
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{5^x2^x}\left(\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^z}\right)  = \\ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{10^x}\left(\dfrac{2}{2-1}\right) = \\ 2\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{10^x} = 2\cdot\dfrac{10}{10-1}=\dfrac{20}{9}={\Large{2}}\frac{2}{9}.\tag{3}$$

---

**D'.**
To make the same calculations without summation signs, one can use this table/illustration to count the reciprocals:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\color{tan}{\times} & \color{tan}{1} & \color{tan}{\frac{1}{2}} & \color{tan}{\frac{1}{2^2}} & \color{tan}{\frac{1}{2^3}} & \color{tan}{\frac{1}{2^4}} & \color{tan}{...} & \color{red}{Sum:} \\
\hline
\color{tan}{1} &  1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2^2} & \frac{1}{2^3} & \frac{1}{2^4} & ... & \color{red}{2}\\  
\hline
\color{tan}{\frac{1}{5}} &  - & \frac{1}{5\cdot 2} & \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^2} & \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^3} & \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^4} & ... & \color{red}{\frac{2}{5\cdot 2}}\\
\hline
\color{tan}{\frac{1}{5^2}}  &  - & - & \frac{1}{5^2\cdot 2^2} & \frac{1}{5^2\cdot 2^3} & \frac{1}{5^2\cdot 2^4} & ... & \color{red}{\frac{2}{5^2\cdot 2^2}}\\
\hline
\color{tan}{\frac{1}{5^3}}  &  - & - & - & \frac{1}{5^3\cdot 2^3} & \frac{1}{5^3\cdot 2^4} & ... & \color{red}{\frac{2}{5^3\cdot 2^2}}\\
\hline\color{tan}{\frac{1}{5^4}}  &  - & - & - & - & \frac{1}{5^4\cdot 2^4} & ... & \color{red}{\frac{2}{5^4\cdot 2^4}}\\
\hline
\color{tan}{\vdots} & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots & \color{red}{\vdots}  \\
\hline 
\color{blue}{Sum:} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\frac{5^2-1}{(5-1)\cdot5\cdot 2}} & \color{blue}{\frac{5^3-1}{(5-1)\cdot5^2\cdot 2^2}} & \color{blue}{\frac{5^4-1}{(5-1)\cdot5^3\cdot 2^3}} & \color{blue}{\frac{5^5-1}{(5-1)\cdot5^4\cdot 2^4}} & \color{blue}\cdots & \color{violet}{=\dfrac{20}{9}} \\
\hline
\end{array}
Note that we used red column to count final sum in $(3)$, since it has easier form (than blue row).

---

**D''.**

To work with $2$-indexed series, we can enumerate these numbers $b_n$ by pair of indices $(x,y)$; then write down them and group in some way.

If we'll group them by index $x$ (power of number $5$), $-$ we'll get red sums from the table;

if we'll group them by index $y$ (power of number $2$), $-$ we'll get blue sums from the table;

we can group them by (nonnegative) difference $\;y-x\;$ too, $-$ so we'll get sums by diagonals of the table.

Actually (since we can pre-estimate that the series is convergent) we can regroup terms according to convenience purposes.

Example of such "diagonal" summation:

$$\Bigl( 1 + \dfrac{1}{5\cdot 2} + \dfrac{1}{5^2\cdot 2^2} +  \dfrac{1}{5^3\cdot 2^3} +  \ldots \Bigr) \\
+ \Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2} +  \dfrac{1}{5\cdot 2^2} +  \dfrac{1}{5^2\cdot 2^3} +   \dfrac{1}{5^3\cdot 2^4} + \ldots \Bigr) \\
+ \Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2^2} +  \dfrac{1}{5\cdot 2^3} +  \dfrac{1}{5^2\cdot 2^4} +   \dfrac{1}{5^3\cdot 2^5} + \ldots \Bigr) \\
+ \Bigl(\dfrac{1}{2^3} +  \dfrac{1}{5\cdot 2^4} +  \dfrac{1}{5^2\cdot 2^5} +   \dfrac{1}{5^3\cdot 2^6} + \ldots \Bigr) \\
+ \ldots \\
= 
\Bigl( 1 + \dfrac{1}{10} + \dfrac{1}{10^2} +  \dfrac{1}{10^3} +  \ldots \Bigr) \\
+ \dfrac{1}{2}\Bigl( 1 +  \dfrac{1}{10} +  \dfrac{1}{10^2} +   \dfrac{1}{10^3} + \ldots \Bigr) \\
+ \dfrac{1}{2^2}\Bigl(1 +  \dfrac{1}{10} +  \dfrac{1}{10^2} +   \dfrac{1}{10^3} + \ldots \Bigr) \\
+ \dfrac{1}{2^3}\Bigl(1 +  \dfrac{1}{10} +  \dfrac{1}{10^2} +   \dfrac{1}{10^3} + \ldots \Bigr) \\
+ \ldots \\
= 
\dfrac{10}{9} + \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{10}{9} +\dfrac{1}{2^2}\cdot \dfrac{10}{9} +\dfrac{1}{2^3}\cdot \dfrac{10}{9} + \ldots \\ =
\dfrac{10}{9}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{2} +\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{2^3} + \ldots \right) \\ = \dfrac{10}{9} \cdot 2 = \dfrac{20}{9}.
 $$

Comment: Oleg i dont see how u get from line 2 to 3 in the series . the step in the sums

Comment: the step where u introduce the sum in terms of a z . ( z=0---> inf)

Comment: $$\sum_{y=x}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^y} =\\ \dfrac{1}{2^x}+\dfrac{1}{2^{x+1}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{x+2}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{x+3}}+\ldots =\\ \dfrac{1}{2^x}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\ldots\right)=$$
and we introduce $z = y-x$ here: from $0$ to $\infty$:
$$
\dfrac{1}{2^x} \left(\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^z}\right).
$$ And then use formula for geometric series to get further steps.

Comment: i cant read that ..i get all the other steps ..geometric series .. just how u re  indexed at step 2 to 3 

Comment: @Randin: I updated the answer with illustrative table.

Comment: Oleg how or why does the sum get split up ? step 2 to 3 ?

Comment: In terms of this table: to find total sum (of the table), - we just count the sum of each row. We can do that since all sub-series are convergent. Some helpful info here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html . But we could count by columns too: each sum in column is just sum of finite amount of numbers.

Comment: Oleg..u just read my mind ..i was going to ask u next to find a similar problem or definition and i think u just have .my confusion stems from what u now defined as double series ..hope that link helps i will let u know .thanksj

Comment: that link applies to step 1 but darn im still not seeing how you are able to put the denominator of 2 back with the 5 in the same series , then introduce a new series in terms of z , then u re indexed it ?? how or why

Comment: fleabloods solution seems easier to understand ..especially at the end of his argument with the dbl series .. he didnt split up the 1/10^x part evaluating it  as is

Comment: AH did u index your double series so that the x's will stay ahead of the y's? Oleg ? as fleablood did with k>m for the expansion to end in 5 .

Comment: I added yet another part of the answer (D'').

Comment: Oleg i appreciate your elaborations but fleablood already simplified the proof of this result . pure math like this is succinct and his proof is ' from the book '  .yours is good too but damn man since when is math run on sentences ?

Answer (score 1):

It's well known and easy to prove that the only $\frac 1{b_i}$ that terminate are $b_i$ of the form $b_i = 2^k 5^m$.

(Because the only divisors of powers of $10$ are $2$ and $5$ so any other prime will never divide into $10^N$ evenly.)

If $b_i = 2^k 5^m$ then either:

1) $k > m$ and $b_i = 2^{k-m}*10^m$ and this will terminate in $5$.

2) $k = m$ and $b_i = 10^m$ and this will terminate in $1$.

or 3) $k < m$ and $b_i = 5^{m-k}*10^k$ and this will terminate with a power of $2$.

3) are not an acceptable option but 1) and 2) are.

So we are dealing with numbers of the form $b_i = 2^j*10^k$ (where $j$ and $k$ may be $0$).

So you sum will be

$\sum_{j=0; k= 0}^{\infty, \infty} \frac 1{2^j}*\frac 1{10^k}$.... *IF* this converges we can rearrange these to

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac 1{10^k}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^j})$

Now you should know that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^j} = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 14 + .... =2$.

So ..... you get $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{10^k}*2 = 2.22222222....... = 2 \frac 29$